# Защита от XSS атак которую я использую

Tags: php, javascript, html

Я создал на своей работе 'Электронный кабинет', работает на PHP, есть возможность добавлять сообщения. Я записываю сообщения от пользователей в БД как есть (ничего не форматирую). Когда данные выводятся в браузер я их форматирую следующим образом:

```
$message = str_replace(array('<', '>'), array('меньше', 'больше'), $msg);
```

Да, это конечно банально =), но мне не нужно что-бы пользователи могли форматировать сообщения. Я не 'съел собаку' в веб-технологиях но основы знаю. Так вот, вопрос следующий: как может злоумышленник вставить свой зловредный js код в мой сайт что-бы он сработал, если я заменяю символы (<,>) с помощью которых браузер понимает что нужно выполнить код или нарисовать теги?

Уточнение: сообщения вводят пользователи и выводятся сообщения тоже пользователям в тег div

Comment: Писать как есть текст от пользователей в базу глупо...Нужно ставить защиту от sql-иньекций

Comment: Я использую класс PDO, параметризированные запросы.

Comment: А через что именно пользователи вводят сообщения? `<input>`?

Comment: Ну и заодно, может ли админ править эти сообщения? Каким образом?

Comment: Да, в input, а какое это имеет значение? Можно же сделать что-бы они вводили сообщение в тег который я захочу =) Править сообщения могу я, я админ.

Comment: Разница огромная. Эксплоит есть в моем ответе

Comment: Уточню: править сообщения я могу не на сайте а в БД

Comment: наши в офисе тоже недавно проблем огребли изза xss. заказывали потом пентест в tomhunter, и спецы наши целый месяц обнаруженные недочеты устраняли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если администратор системы будет иметь возможность править сообщения средствами системы, то вы в опасности.

Вот пример сообщения с эксплоитом, позволяющего при некоторых условиях выполнить код у администратора системы:

```
" onclick="alert('XSS here!');"
```

Пример использования в реальной разметке:

```
<input type="text" value="" onclick="alert('XSS here!');">
```

Как следствие, кроме симоволов `<` и `>` нужно экранировать еще и кавычки (`"`) и апострофы (`'`).

А вообще, правильнее всего было бы заменять **все** специальные символы, на аналогичные HTML сущности. В PHP для этого есть [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: Я может быть Вас не правильно понял, но вот что выведет в браузер из БД приведённое вами сообщение: меньшеinput type="text" value="" onclick="alert('XSS here!');"больше

Comment: речь не о выводе, а о редактировании сообщения администратором. Само собщение в первом блоке, а второй блок, это результат рендеринга формы редактирования

Comment: я уже ответил что редактировать сообщения могу только я, я админ, могу править только в БД

Comment: @alek.kov, на что я изменил ответ, добавив туда блок с "_Если_".

Comment: сейчас понял про что Вы имели ввиду, и правда, если буду делать правку сообщений админом - обязательно учту этот момент, спасибо! =)

Comment: @alek.kov, думаю вам стоит сразу учесть этот момент, чтобы не было неожиданностей в будущем ;)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого имеются специальные функции `strip_tags()`, которая удаляет тэги и `htmlspecailchars()`, которая заменяет HTML-сущности `<`, `>`, `&` их HTML-эквивалентами.

Comment: Вопрос не в том как я могу форматировать данные (я сказал как я делаю, я хочу делать так), вопрос в том что в моей ситуации это получается 100% защита от XSS атак, так что-ли? =)